# Photo uploading PHP undefined index. Insert photo into sql database

Tags: php, html, sql, image-uploading

I'm working right now with a registration form that allows photo uploading for a profile picture. When attempting to submit everything works successfully except the errors given by the picture index.

I highly believe it has to do with running the php within the form as the picture isn't uploaded to the variable before submitting but I can't get past it.

**Notice: Undefined index: photo in /var/www/registeraccount.php on line 54**

**Notice: Undefined index: photo in /var/www/registeraccount.php on line 57**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',"On");
include ('database_connection.php');
$target = "/var/www/profile";

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message  
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name ';//add to array "error"
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];//else assign it a variable
    }

    if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
    } else {


        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
           //regular expression for email validation
            $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
        } else {
             $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
        }


    }


    if (empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
    } else {
        $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    }


    if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '

    { // If everything's OK...

        // Make sure the email address is available:
        $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM account  WHERE email ='$Email'";
        $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
        if (!$result_verify_email) {//if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_email==false)
            echo ' Database Error Occured ';
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email .


            // Create a unique  activation code:
            $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            $target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
            $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);



            $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `account` ( `username`, `passwords`, `email`, `picture`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Password', '$Email ' , '$pic')";


            $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
            if (!$result_insert_user) {
                echo 'Query Failed ';
            }

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.


                // Send the email:
                $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
                $message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/activate.php?email=' . urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation";
                mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: systemadminstrator@theanimator.com');

                // Flush the buffered output.


                // Finish the page:
                echo '<div class="success">Thank you for
registering! A confirmation email
has been sent to '.$Email.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';


            } else { // If it did not run OK.
                echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system
error. We apologize for any
inconvenience.</div>';
            }

        } else { // The email address is not available.
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email
address has already been registered.
</div>';
        }

    } else {//If the "error" array contains error msg , display them



echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
        foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

            echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';



        }
        echo '</ol></div>';

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);//Close the DB Connection

} // End of the main Submit conditional.



?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Registration Form</title>





<style type="text/css">
//CSS Once again removed because it has nothing to do with the issue.
</style>

</head>
<body>


<form action="registeraccount.php" method="post" class="registration_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form </legend>

    <h2 style="text-align:center">Create an account!</h2>
    <p style="text-align:center"> <span>Already a member? <a href="login.php">Log in</a></span> </p>

    <div class="elements">
      <label for="name">Name :</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="e-mail">E-mail :</label>
      <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" size="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="Password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" size="25" />
      <p>
              Photo:
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
            <input type="file" name="photo"> 
            <p>
      </div>

      <br />

    <div class="submit">
     <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
      <input type="submit" value="Register" />

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button onclick="window.location='theanimator.html';">Go Back!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From what I can tell so far, you're assigning `$target` as `/var/www/profile` without an ending `/`, could be one problem. Try adding one to it = `/var/www/profile/`.

Comment: It's a notice, and it happens when user didn't upload a photo

Comment: u_mulder I'm testing with an image. Going to try the slash now and will text Fred. Will post results

Comment: Nope didn't work. Strangely looking into SQLWorkbench the column picture isn't NULL but blank... Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ZachHarvey Ok, keep me posted. Something that seems strange is the double-up `$target` in `$target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);`.

Comment: Indefined index 'photo'. Maybe your FILE field has another name?

Comment: @ZachHarvey Where are your assigned variables for `'$name', '$Password', '$Email ' , '$pic'`? Maybe you should declare those at the start. Plus, INSERT INTO account (omitted backticks) I doubt `account` needs backticks, not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for responses. Fred I've looked into that but I've declared them in an if statement if they pass verification. I'm now thinking pic is the only think that doesn't get defined properly

Comment: On line 43 `$query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM account` - `account` has no backticks, but you have backticks on line 61.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses provided. First response down below was my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a simple matter of adding a condition to check if a photo is uploaded

```
if(!isset($_FILES['photo'])) {
    $error[] = "No photo selected !";
}
```

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU SO MUCH! 
Works perfectly. I never confirmed to make sure the picture was there so the global variable never got recorded! It makes clear sense now! Thank you so much ionutvmi!!!!

Comment: This does work for the name but doesn't actually upload the photo. I know this isn't best practise because of the space it can start taking up but when trying to use the photo on the profile page it won't work unless uploaded

Comment: i think you need to use a default image in case the user doesn't upload one and change your code to do if(isset($_FILES['photo'])) { // do the upload} else { // add default image }

Comment: Thank you once again ionutvmi!